# Script to ssh to remote server and overwrite file

Tags: ssh, raspberry-pi, paramiko, ssh-keys, raspbian

Been toying around with my Raspberry Pi running raspbian.

I'd like to update a webpage with a shell script that requires no input, such as password.
I just tried creating the keys and putting them in the .ssh file on the remote server, but when I run my simple shell script of ssh user@domain.net 'ls' and it still prompts me for a password.

I also looked into paramiko slightly, but didn't get very far with it.

All I need is to update/replace an html file with text/information that I have.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think your Public/Private Keys for Authentication is not configured correctly in your server.
Can you check this link which explains the authentication step:[SSH Authentication](http://wiki.centos.org/HowTos/Network/SecuringSSH#head-9c5717fe7f9bb26332c9d67571200f8c1e4324bc)

Comment: Yep. It doesn't prompt me if I just want to ssh normally, but running my script it ends up prompting  me.